# Get the mat-table headers in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a mat-table in angular and I want to get the header's title of each column using the typescript code, is there any way to do it?

HTML Code:

```
<mat-table id="emp_table" #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="number">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="matHeader"> Number
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.number}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="matHeader"> Name
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="mobile">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="matHeader"> Mobile
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.mobile}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

TS Code:

`displayedColumns = ['number', 'name', 'mobile'];`

So, what I want is to get the titles: "Number", "Name", "Mobile" from the html using ts all at once using loop, because maybe in the future the table get bigger so I want to get all the titles dynamically.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As Efkah says, normally you use the another aproach. You has two variables

```
  displayedColumns=['number','name','mobile']
  headersColumns=['Number', 'Name','Mobile']
```

And use:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns;let i=index"
        [matColumnDef]="column">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="matHeader"> 
       {{headers[i]}}
  </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row[column]}} </mat-cell>
 </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do very easy the other way round, just define the Headers in the code-behind file:

TS Code:

```js
const numberTitle = 'Number';
```

HTML Code:

```html
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="matHeader">
    {{ numberTitle }}
</mat-header-cell>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I meant getting all the titles at once like in loop for example,I think my question wasn’t clear, I will edit it

Comment: I still don't seem to get the use-case here. you could still use a title-lookup? like `{{ title['number'] }}` and `const title = { number: 'Number' }`. In a real-world example you would use a `translationService` to translate the headers, like `{{ 'i18n.number' | translate }}` and its easy to use column-name here to get the current translation in ts via something like `this.translationService.translate('i18n.' + matColumnName)` - you just have to stick to your conventions.